# Or statement not working properly

Tags: python

Please help me with this problem

```
# something about if/else and strings

# we ask the user for input
print "Enter something"
text = raw_input("> ")


# Let's see if it contains a vowel
for i in text:
    if i in "aeiou":
        print "It contains a vowel"
        break

for i in text:
    if i == ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"):
        print "It contains a wwwwovel."
        break
```

Hello!

I have this little piece of code, it works, but it doesn't how I suppose it should. For example, when I type in the words `sta`, the result is:

```
It contains a vowel
It contains a wwwwovel.
```

On the other hand, when I type `sto`, the answer is:

```
It contains a vowel
```

The program should print the same results as `sta` when I type `sto`.
Please help me.

Thank you!